On a conditional expectation property; substitution rule
For days now, I've been trying to prove the identity $$E(f(X,Y)\mid Y=y)=E(f(X,y)\mid Y=y).$$ I have found a couple of posts about this identity,   mainly this one, and the more I think about this and read on conditional expectation, I'm inclined to believe that the RHS seems to not make sense. The LHS is simply a function $g(y)$ for which, if we plug in $Y$, we get $$g(Y)=E(f(X,Y)\mid Y)=E(f(X,Y)\mid\sigma(Y)).$$ But the RHS I simply can not comprehend and therefor how to prove the formula.
I am mainly making this post since I did not feel like the answer in the linked post was completely answering the question. I'd be very grateful if someone could explain the formula and the RHS in more detail to me. This is partly an exercise in Gut's An Intermediate Course in Probability. Most of the properties of conditional expectation make sense to me, but I'm doubting the mere expression on the RHS, so I don't know how to proceed.

The RHS makes sense. Take the special case $f(X,Y)=g(X)h(Y)$ for which the identity is almost trivial. Most proofs build on that using a monotone class argument.

Ok, thanks. How would one prove the formula in this special case? I am familiar with the property $E(f(X)Y\mid X)=f(X)E(Y\mid X)$, but here we are not conditioning on a random variable, so I am a bit unsure if/how pulling-out-what-is-known applies.

Take the special case and condition on $Y,.$ Then use the Doob-Dynkin lemma to express the conditional expectation as a function of $Y,.$ That function is it that you wrote as $\mathbb E[f(X,Y)|Y=y],.$

I am still a bit confused. We have $E(g(X)h(Y)\mid Y)$, and this is a $\sigma(Y)$-measurable random variable, so it is a function of $Y$. How do you go from this observation to $E(f(X,y)\mid Y=y)$?

By the Doob-Dynkin Lemma  $E[,g(X)\mid Y,]=\ell(Y)$  for some Borel measurable $\ell:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R,.$ Now combine this with the well-known facts $$E[,g(X),h(Y)\mid Y,]=h(Y),E[,g(X)\mid Y,]$$ and $$h(y),E[,g(X)\mid Y,]=E[,g(X),h(y)\mid Y,],.$$ Finally write $Y=y$ after the vertical bar (which comes from just another instance of the Doob-Dynkin lemma).

@KurtG. Thank you. I have a hard time seeing the chain of equalities that lead to the desired formula. We have $$E[,g(X),h(Y)\mid Y,]=h(Y),E[,g(X)\mid Y,]=h(Y)\ell(Y),$$but I don't see how to continue from here. I guess you need to change $h(Y)$ to $h(y)$ it seems. Moreover, how does the Doob-Dynkin lemma imply that $E(g(X)h(y)\mid Y)$ can be written $E[,g(X)h(y)\mid Y=y,]$? According to the lemma, I suppose $E[,g(X)h(y)\mid Y,]$ is a function of $Y$, but I don't see why we can simply replace the $Y$ after the vertical bar with $Y=y$.

The problem is that the conditional expectation is a global concept, not a poitwise one. In $E[f(X,y)\mid Y=y]$ it is understood that we are choosing the value in $y$ of each $E[f(X,y)\mid Y]$ , but that value is not defined if $P(Y=y)=0$.

@Speltzu That was helpful, thanks. Is there a definition of $E[f(X,y)\mid Y]$? Is it a function of $Y$ or $y$, or both? The reason I'm asking is because I really understand the LHS side of the formula in the OP, but the RHS still eludes me. That is why I am stuck on how to prove this.

@Speltzu. I totally disagree. The notation $|Y=y]$ confuses a lot of people because they think we condition on a probability zero event. We don't. That notation means  $\mathbb E[Z|Y=y]$ is the function $\ell$ evaluated at $y$ which exists by Doob-Dynkin.

Yes, but what version $l$ of $E[Z\mid Y]$ do we take?

We fix a version. In OP's case and the special case I suggested, we fix the $\ell$ that satisfies $\mathbb E[g(X)|Y]=\ell(Y)$ and the $k$ that satisfies $\mathbb E[g(X)h(Y)|Y]=k(Y),.$ Then we get $h(Y)\ell(Y)=k(Y),.$ What OP wants to prove is nothing else than this equation in a notation that arguably confuses most people.

It's not that easy: In $E[g(X)h(y)\mid Y]=k_y(Y)$ you have to fix $k_y$ for each $y$, and if $Y$ is continuous, you could choose an arbitrary value of $k_y(y)$ for each $y$.

In short, the expression $E[f(X,Y)\mid Y=y]=E[f(X,y)\mid Y=y]$, as it is, does not make sense so it can hardly be proven . It may make sense, and be valid, if we understand that we have previously chosen a certain version of $E[f(X,y)\mid Y]$ for each $y$, which can be done in most cases, as , for example, when there is a regular conditional probability $P_{\Omega/Y}$.
